# Android Timer in Background Service not updating on time

Tags: java, android, timer, runnable, android-handler

I am trying to update a user location to our REST WebService every minute.  I have tried using a Timer and a Runnable with Handler. Both of these are having problems.

Both work fine on my Emulator, although on our test devices the timer and Runnable are not running every minute, they update sporadically, sometimes within 1 second of each other, sometimes 5 minutes later, and anywhere in between..

Does anyone know why this might happen?

```
Context context;
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    context = this;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0); 
} 

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateLocation(context);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you share your handler/runnable code? I recently followed this tutorial on creating a repeating runnable and it worked well for my use case: http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

the "trick" is to call `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` inside your runnable

Comment: I have added my code.  It updates the first time straight away, then 1 minute intervals after that.  Works fine in emulator, doesn't work on devices.

Comment: Okay, found the issue... We have build variants and my testers are running multiple apps with the same login, so multiple background services are running on their devices, which are updating their locations at all different times... So they are working every minute, it's just that they have X amount of services updating every minute.